# Calling NSXMLParser with different variables depending on which button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

How do i change the temporaryDateVariable properly?

Have tried nested If-statements, if else statements and so on.

What i want to do is for the IBaction that is called under three different buttons to change the temporaryDateVariable so that the different buttons send different data so that i can collect different data under the `-(void)parser:parserDidEndDocument` delegate method

```
-(IBAction)sendXmlData:(id)sender {
    if([self button1pressed]){
        temporaryDateVariable  = date1Variable
    }              
    if([self button2pressed]) {
        temporaryDateVariable  = date2Variable            
    }
    if([self button3pressed]) {                
        temporaryDateVariable  = date3Variable
    }
    NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<xml-string>",temporaryDateVariable]
    //lots of nsxmlparserstuff, that is working.
}
```

The result out of this is that the last date always prevails.

Comment: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<xml-string>",temporaryDateVariable] won't work. There is no format specifier in the format string.

Comment: <xml-string> is a complete soap 1.1 message, i just chose to write <xml-message> instead because the message is just too long to show. 

If you would, could u please give me a code-example to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: I resolved this issue by assigning tag variables to each of the three buttons, and the problem had nothing to do with the postString**

by assigning tag variables to all of the buttons.

So by doing this.

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{

         button1.tag = x;
         button2.tag = y;
         button3.tag = z;
    }



        -(IBAction)sendXmlData:(id)sender {

        switch ( ((UIButton *)sender).tag ) {

            case x:
                temporaryDateVariable = date1Variable;
            break;
            case y:
                temporaryDateVariable = date2Variable;

        }

             // same old same old
```

}

It actually works.